# Need urgent help in Applying for u.k Direct transit Visa from london

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, british-airways

I am Indian national, with students one year Visa studying in France. 
For two months vacation, I have booked a round trip flight ticket from Paris to Delhi with transit in London Heathrow airport and vice versa(same)
I arrive in London Heathrow airport at 10.20 P.M and my departing flight to Delhi is on next day 10.00 A.M.. I arrive and depart from the same terminal! 
I have been told that I need to get transit Visa here in France!
My questions are- 
1. Is the direct transit Visa that I get is applicable for the full round trip, or should I get one while going to India and again another while coming from India? 
2. If I apply for direct transit Visa online, should I get separate appointment for biometric registration or just by applying for direct transit Visa I will be called for biometric registration !

Comment: Your one-year French visa, which must be a type D visa, exempts you from the requirement for both the [direct airside transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no) and the [visitor in transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes).  So who told you that you "need to get transit Visa here in France"?  They seem to be wrong.

Comment: Hi phoog..yes I have Type D french student visa.  I spoke with British airways customer service, the customer service executive said it's necessary for me to get the U.K direct transit Visa. But they were not having answers for those questions I mentioned above! Thank you in advance for helps!

Comment: @phoog The second link in the comment states that the flight should leave on same day for exemption to visitor in transit visa for holders of D visa. That is not the OP's case.

Comment: @RedBaron The page says "have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive," and the departure here is before midnight on the day after arrival.

Comment: @phoog Ah my mistake. I misread it.